# Toggle state from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm pretty new to React and Redux so I may be doing this completely the wrong way, in fact judging from a few other answers to similar questions on here I suspect I'm doing quite a lot wrong.

I've got a button in my 'Layout' component which adds a class to a div, this class comes from a state. The button is a toggle and will turn the state & class on and off (this will result in making a menu appear and dimming the rest of the page).

However I also want any interaction with the 'Nav' component (which lives inside a 'Header' component which in turn lives in 'Layout') to also toggle the state & class (so clicking a link collapses the menu). In jQuery/VanillaJS this was incredibly easy but I can't seem to work out the React/Redux way of doing this.

Layout Component: https://pastebin.com/WzpbeSw7

Header Component: https://pastebin.com/c34NFtUx (probably not relevant but here for reference)

Nav Component: https://pastebin.com/EsJDuLQc

Comment: You don't need to access another component,just change the state another component binded.

Comment: I've changed the links to use https, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using redux :

You can have a state like toggleBlaBla : "show" . If you connected your react component to state of redux by using react-redux , whenever you dispatch an action for changing toggleBlaBla to "hide", your connected component will rerender.

By using only react :

If you want two components to change some ui state by some events, it is a good idea to put them in a container component, so that whenever your state changes these two components rerender with your changed state passing to both components.

Comment: Well this is the problem I have. I know how to give the child component the state value but when I click the child component I need that state value to reset. I need a way to update the state on the parent FROM the child.

Comment: Is it possible to put them in a container component ?  Or actually, if you are using redux, make a redux action for changing this ui state in your  state object tree. So that if your store gets a dispatch it will rerender components which you have connected by react-redux

Comment: I knew that redux would be more useful than just getting data from mongodb! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to do the following:

In Layout component:

- On line 26 change `<Header / >` to: `<Header handleNavClick={this.toggleNav.bind(this)} / >`

In Header component:

- On line 10 change `<Navigation position="header" />` to:  `<Navigation closeNav={this.props.handleNavClick.bind(this)} position="header" />`

In Navigation component:

- On line 16 change `return <li key={item._id}><Link to={item.slug}>{item.name}</Link></li>` to: `return <li key={item._id}><Link to={item.slug} onClick={this.props.closeNav.bind(this)}>{item.name}</Link></li>`

Passing the props in this way will allow you to reference reference the toggleNav function inside of Layout and then will update the state accordingly.

*** Note, you may get a binding error such as `React component methods may only be bound to the component instance.`.

- If this happens, you will need to define a function on the Navigation component instead of using `this.props.closeNav` directly. You would need to create a function in Navigation like this: `closeNav() { this.props.closeNav.bind(this) }`.  Don't forget to update the function on the `<Link />` component to `this.closeNav.bind(this)`